# Issue with Related Post Javascript in Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, json, web, blogger

I have created a related post javascript for blogger.com based blogs. The related post plugins loops though the label attached to the current post and displays other posts with the same label.

You can find that in action @ http://www.techquark.com/2017/07/infocus-turbo-5-affordable-powerful.html

The issue is I want to skip the current post to be shown in the related post, but unable to achieve the same.

PFB the javascript code :

```
$(".related-ready").each(function() {
    var b = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + b + "?alt=json-in-script&max-results=3",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(e) {
            var u = "";
            var h = '<div class="related">';
            for (var i = 0; i < e.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < e.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                    if (e.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                        u = e.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                        break
                    }
                }
                var g = e.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
                var c = e.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
                var $c = $('<div>').html(c);
                if (c.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/") > -1) {
                    var p = e.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
                    var k = p
                } else if (c.indexOf("<img") > -1) {
                    var q = $c.find('img:first').attr('src');
                    var k = q
                } else {
                    var k = NO_IMAGE
                }
                h += '<li><div class="related-thumb"><a class="related-img" href="' + u + '" style="background:url(' + k + ') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"/></div><h3 class="related-title"><a href="' + u + '">' + g + '</a></h3></li>'
            }
            h += '</div><div class="clear"/>';
            $(".related-ready").html(h);
            $('.related-img').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('style', function(i, src) {
                    return src.replace('/default.jpg', '/hqdefault.jpg')
                }).attr('style', function(i, src) {
                    return src.replace('s72-c', 's1600')
                })
            })
        }
    })
});
```

TIA !

Comment: add some sort of id to those posts. While displaying, check for that id, and display accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check whether the current Post's ID matches with the ID of the post in feed and then skip that post, the code will look like -

```
....
for (var i = 0; i < e.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    if(e.feed.entry[i].id.$t.split("post-")[1] === "<data:post.id/>"){
        break;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < e.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
....
```